# Haskell: Rigid type variable error when pattern matching bind operator

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, monads

I'm trying to run this

```
newtype Test a = Test (Int, a)

instance Monad Test where
    Test (_, []) >>= k =
        k []
    Test (_, a) >>= k =
        k a
    return a =
        Test (0, a)
```

And I get the error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[t0]'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for >>= :: Test a -> (a -> Test b) -> Test b
      at C:\Users\david.phillips\Documents\code\test.hs:4:5
In the pattern: []
In the pattern: (_, [])
In the pattern: Test (_, [])
```

I get a similar error when I tried using a case statement instead of 2 versions of >>=.

I'm fairly new to haskell and can't see why this wouldn't work.

---

Edit: Sorry, it's a bad example. Suppose that the first definition of >>= gave a different output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
class Monad m where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
  return :: a -> m a
  fail :: String -> m a
```

`Monad` instances are parameterized over a type variable `a`. You are essentially claiming that it is not, because in the place of that variable, you have pattern matched on the empty list constructor, `[]`, meaning "a is a list of something." The type of eg. bind could, with explicit quantification, be written:

`(>>=) :: forall a. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`

Your definition cannot possibly hold for ALL `a`.

Comment: Alright, I think I've got it thanks. I can't pattern match across types when the type isn't given.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to Sarah's answer, you can actually omit your specific pattern match,

```
 Test (_, []) >>= f = f []
```

is the same as

```
 Test (_, a) >>= f = f a
```

So you can really just write this as

```
 Test (_, a) >>= f = f a
 return a          = (0, a)
```

---

Now remember that in addition to have the right types, we're supposed to have that

```
 m >>= return    = m
 return a >>= f  = f a
 (a >>= b) >>= c = a >>= (\a' -> b a' >>= c)
```

This worries me though, as

```
 m = Test (1, 'c')
 m >>= return === return 'c' === (0, 'c') /== m
```

So `return` is no longer functioning as an identity and you're breaking the 1st monad law. Fixing this would mean `return` would have to preserve the first element of the tuple, problematic since we don't actually tell it about it.

Naively, let's just clobber the first tuple element that our function returns.

```
 Test (a, b) >>= f = Test (a, snd (f b))
```

Now

```
 Test (1, 'c') >>= return == Test (1, snd (return 'c')) == Test (1, 'c')
```

But we're still in trouble,

```
 let f a = Test (1, a)
 return a >>= f == Test (0, snd (f a)) == Test (0, a) /== f a
```

So the trick here is to do what the state monad does

```
 newtype Test a = Test{ unTest :: Int -> (Int, a) }

 instance Monad Test where
   return a = Test $ \i -> (i, a)
   (Test m) >>= f = Test $ \i -> let (i', a) = m i
                    in unTest (f a) $ i'
```

Which does satisfy the monad laws*. Happily this already exists in `Control.Monad.State`.

** modulo `seq`

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example. Suppose that `Test (_, []) >>= f` gave a different output. As `a` can be any type, I thought that I would be able to have different patterns for the different types that `a` can be. I'm going through a haskell tutorial, and only just arrived at monads, so I'm not sure about the laws.

Comment: @Zantier Haskell won't let you pattern match across random type variables, though I can see why'd you'd think that. The gist of the laws is to make sure monads behave "sanely". You're current definition of a this monad actually does some really weird things. Like replacing `m` with `m >>= return` gives different results.

Comment: I've written out the laws, they're just 3 equations that lal monads are supposed to do. Combinators depend on them so  if you try to use one and you don't satisfy the laws, things can get hairy

Comment: I don't know enough yet to get all of that yet, but I'll come back to it. Thanks a bunch. The fpcomplete tutorial exercies seem to have really dropped me in the deep end, but I'm sure it'll make sense eventually.

Comment: @Zantier It will :) Good luck! We've all been there

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the first pattern. You are trying to make a separate definition for a specific type, which you can't do. All of the definitions need to be for all types `a`. If you could violate that, the first pattern would be the same as the second pattern but with `a` bound to `[]`, so just write:

```
instance Monad Test where
    Test (_, a) >>= k =
        k a
    return a =
        Test (0, a)
```

`Test (0, []) >>= k` would then match the `>>=` pattern, and become `k []`, exactly the same as what your first pattern is unnecessarily trying to do.